# How do I add formulas to Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I add a formula like:

```
=SUM(A1:A17)
```

to a range of fields using Google Apps Script for Google Sheets?

Comment: Are you looking for the same formula ```=SUM(A1:A17)``` in a range of cells, or do you want to change the range within the sum based on where you are in the sheet?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This is done using the [setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String)) for a selected cell. Below is an example of how to do this.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
cell.setFormula("=SUM(B3:B4)");
```

You can also use [setFormulaR1C1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulaR1C1(String)) to create R1C1 notation formulas. Example below.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
// This sets the formula to be the sum of the 3 rows above B5
cell.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])");
```

To add several formulas to several fields use [setFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String)). Example below

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This sets the formulas to be a row of sums, followed by a row of averages right below.
// The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.
var formulas = [
  ["=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=SUM(D2:D4)"],
  ["=AVERAGE(B2:B4)", "=AVERAGE(C2:C4)", "=AVERAGE(D2:D4)"]
];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5:D6");
cell.setFormulas(formulas);
```

Comment: For info, this is a very bad answer...no idea why it has been accepted and up voted. Refer to documentation to see how to get a range, setFormula is a range method (and it was so in 2012 as well :-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas please post your method then

Comment: I think setFormula works but I agree that how to use it should be described better in the answer instead of focusing on how to select the cell.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more general answer.

Suppose you want to populate column B with a formula that is the value of column A, plus 1. For example,the formula in cell B1 would be "=A1 + 1".

Let's stipulate that first row of the range is 1, and the last is 20.

```
// create an array the same size as the number of rows.
var data = [];
// populate the array with the formulas.
for (var i=0; i < 20; i++)
{
  // note that as usual, each element of the array must itself be an array 
  // that has as many elements as columns. (1, in this case.)
    data[i] = ['=A' + (i+1).toString() + ' + 1 ' ];
}
// set the column values.
sheet.getRange(1,2,20,1).setFormulas(data);
```

Making this work for different numbers of rows, and different starting row,
is a matter of using variables instead of the hard-coded 1 and 20 in this example.

Answer (score 6):

Set, Copy & Paste in a range

If you want for example A18 to hold the formula '=SUM(A1:A17)' and the same for columns B to Z you can set the formula in A18 and then **copy** A18 to B18:Z18. The same thing holds for more complicated ranges. The easiest to get going is to use the macro recorder and then inspect your script.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
sheet.getRange('A18').setFormula('=SUM(A1:A17)');
sheet.getRange('A18').copyTo(sheet.getRange('B18:Z18'));
//There are other parameters to 'copyTo' that you can use if needed
```

Comment: The three-parameter [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) isn't necessary, because the defaults are already `PASTE_NORMAL` and `false` (don't transpose). Nothing wrong with using the single-parameter short version, right?

Comment: Yes Martin, you are right. I made the example code more succinct now with the comment that there are other parameters for the 'copyTo' function that can be used if needed.

Answer (score 5):

I used the copyTo formula suggested by [Frans Van Assche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/915197/frans-van-assche), but used conversions from numeric rows and columns to A1 notation because I didn't have a predefined range. For example, the following code sums each row, not including the header, from column D to however many columns of data were created earlier in the totals column C.

```
  const startRow = 2; // first row to sum
  const startCol = 4; // first column to sum
  let endCol = sheet.getLastColumn(); // last column with data
  let endRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // last row with data
  let sumRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, 1, endCol - startCol + 1); // range for first cell of formula
  let copyRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol - 1, endRow - 1, 1); // range to copy formulas into
  let sumFormula = "=SUM(" + sumRange.getA1Notation() + ")"; // define formula
  let totalsCol = startCol - 1; // this could be whichever column you want the totals to be in, for example, a constant or endCol + 1 if you want the totals at the end
  let startCell = sheet.getRange(startRow, totalsCol); // first cell to copy formula into
  startCell.setFormula(sumFormula); // add formula to first cell
  startCell.copyTo(copyRange); // copy formula from first cell to other range
```

Answer (score 3):

setValues() is also working in place of setFormulas()

```
  var disht = spss.getSheetByName("DI");
  var divals = disht.getRange("A1:G50").getValues();
  divals[40][5]= "=round(SUM(F10:F39),0)"; //F41 =round(SUM(F10:F39),0)
  divals[42][5]= "=(F42+F41)*(F8/100)";  //F43 =(F42+F41)*(F8/100)
  divals[43][5]= '=if(G8>0,(F41+F42)*(G8/100),"")' ; //F44 =if(G8>0,(F41+F42)*(G8/100),"")
  divals[44][5]= '=if(isblank($G$7),"",sum($F$41:$F$44)*$G$7*0.01)';//F45 =if(isblank($G$7),"",sum($F$41:$F$44)*$G$7*0.01)
  divals[45][5]= '=round(F41,0)+round(F42,0)+round(F43,0)+round(F44,0)+round(F45,0)' ; //F46 =round(F41,0)+round(F42,0)+round(F43,0)+round(F44,0)+round(F45,0)
  divals[47][5]= "=F46-F47"; //F48 =F46-F47
  divals[44][4]= '=if(isblank($G$7),"","TCS")'; //E45  =if(isblank($G$7),"","TCS")
  disht.getRange("A1:G50").setValues(divals);
```