# Google Scripts won't return hyperlinks in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on the very early stages of a video game economy tracker to eventually implement better economy dynamics into future MMORPGs. So, first I am trying to create a Google spreadsheet to keep track of the prices, here's the relevant snippet of code in Google Scripts. As far as I can tell, Google Scripts uses the exact same functionality as **JavaScript**.

```
function makeLink(item) {
  var encodedItem = encodeURI(underScore(toTitleCase(item)));
  //make spaces into underscores, then URL-encode the rest

  var wiki = "http://wiki.videogame_address.org/"; 
  //the base wiki URL for the video game

  wikiLink = wiki+encodedItem;
  //link to the item in the wiki      

  var href = "=HYPERLINK(\""+wikiLink+"\",\""+toTitleCase(item)+"\")";
  //attempting to have Google Spreadsheet make a URL
  //yields =HYPERLINK("http://wiki.videgame.org/Giant_Head","Giant Head")


  return href;
};
```

The resulting href variable only gives the text output

`=HYPERLINK("http://wiki.videgame.org/Giant_Head","Giant Head")`

This is the exact correct syntax for the spreadsheet to create a link, however, it just leaves it as text. Is there a way to force Google to digest the text that is output here instead of leaving it as text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-to-add-formula-to-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-scripts

Answer (score 3):

Use the `setFormula` method:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets().shift();
var cell = sheet.setActiveCell("B5");
var newLink = makeLink("whatever");
cell.setFormula(newLink);
```

References:

- [How do I add formulas to Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-to-add-formula-to-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-scripts)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..
http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1592

It appears that this feature is not available and will not be available. :(

If you are willing to skip on the text-display 'Giant Head', you can at least return link for a working link.

```
function makeLink(item) {
  var encodedItem = encodeURI(underScore(toTitleCase(item)));
  var wiki = "http://wiki.videogame_address.org/"; 
  wikiLink = wiki+encodedItem;     
  return wikiLink;
};
```