# How to use for to sum a range in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I want create a simple custom sum formula in google Spreadsheets using google app Script.

```
 function somaDias(range, days) {
   var sum = 0;

   for(i=0; i<days; i++){
     sum = sum + range[i];
  }


    return soma;
    }
```

I will use this function in a report that has a column with monetary values for each day of the month. The idea is to select the whole column of values, pass it as a range and them sum this values up to a day of the month. I know there is something wrong with

```
  sum = sum + range[i];
```

because, when I test it with a column that has only 1... the return is "0111111"

=somaDias(C9:C15;6) // should return 6, but it returns 0111111

I don´t want to use =sum(), because the range changes according to the day. I want to pass as the range the 30 days of the month and then pass the number of days I want to sum. If I used sum, I would have to reselect the range everyday....

What I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not using the spreadsheet built in function `SUM()` ? (doc [here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?rd=2))

[image]

---

edit following comment.

I don't like custom functions but here is a way to achieve what you want : use only 1 parameter = number of days, it will count from the first column.

```
function somaDias(days) {
  var sum = 0;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sh.getRange(sh.getActiveCell().getRowIndex(),1,1,days).getValues();

  for(var i in values[0]){
    sum += values[0][i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-do-i-add-formulas-to-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script

Answer (score 2):

If you loop through the values you can use the function below. You can specify the object and what column index needs to be summed.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F30");
var values = range.getValues();


function sum( obj, colindex ) {
  var sum = 0;
  for( var el in obj ) {
      sum += parseFloat( obj[el][colindex] );
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First. Always a range is a 2 dimensional array: range[row][column]. So if you are working with only one column, you must work with range[i][0] and iterate on i. Second thing, when the function finds an empty cell, it changes the type to what it should return. Anyway an empty cell counts as zero as a number. So to solve this just add

```
if (range[i][j] != 0) sum = sum + range[i][j];
```

and it will avoid working with empty cells.
Hope this helps you.