# How to SUM two numeric ranges using scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question in regard to summing two columns with numeric values. I am confident that I have got the right variables in terms of ranges but have problems summing this up. I know the issue is based on how the script stores data and therefore you can not just sum them up. However I would appreciate if anyone has a smart workaround.

```
if (sheetGeneral.getRange('H1').getValue() == 'Sunday') {
    var Sunday = sheetGeneral.getRange(4,sheetGeneral.getLastColumn(),52,1).getValues
    var Saturday = sheetGeneral.getRange(4,sheetGeneral.getLastColumn()-1,52,1).getValues
    Sonntag.setValues(Saturday+Sunday)  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting a range with multiple values. Try the solution from this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24999265/5995040):

```
for(var i in values[0]){
    sum += values[0][i];
  }
```

Apply this to your function that calculate the sum of each range, then add the total of both ranges.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems logical. Will try it out once I get access to my PC!

Answer (score 0):

Sunday and Saturday will be arrays so you can't just add them together.

If they only have single values then you can add them like so:

```
Sonntag.setValues(Saturday[0][0]+Sunday[0][0])
```

If they have multiple values then one you can add them like this:

```
var combined = saturday.map(function(value, index) {
    return [saturday[index][0] + sunday[index][0]];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. based on single values it worked smoothly. Unfortunately I have multiple values and it gives me the following error "Cannot find function map in object function getValues() {/* */}. (line 41, file "Code")". I do have a work around by pasting both ranges into a separate sheet and having =SUM formula and then copying that range into the right column. It works in practise, but is not as "sexy".