# Import multiple ranges from one Google Sheet into another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to import multiple sheets in one Google Sheet into another Google workbook. I can get `ImportRange` to work for one sheet but how do I use it for multiple sheets, or alternatively, how do I combine multiple `ImportSheets` in one column?

```
=unique(
importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...",
    "'Kramerville KH'!d5:o1000"))
```

I want to be able to add another range to that, e.g. `'Emalahleni KH'!d5: o1000`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use formula:

```
={unique(importrange("link...","'Sheet1'!d5:o1000"));
unique(importrange("link...","'Sheet2'!d5:o1000"))}
```

The result is two imports one behind another, see [more info here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

There's no better way to do this. Alternative is to combine formula as text and then convert string into furmula using script. See how in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198117/fill-arrayformula-with-dynamic-importrange).

Answer (score 0):

Although the existing answer has been accepted the question appears to require exclusion of duplicates not only from within each range but also across ranges:

```
=unique({unique(importrange(" l i n k ","'Kramerville KH'!d5:o1000"));unique(importrange(" l i n k ","'Emalahleni KH'!d5:o1000"))})
```