# use JOIN to pull multiple IMPORTRANGES into SORT(ARRAYFORMULA({importrange1; importrange2; etc}

Tags: function, join, google-sheets, importrange

How can I use JOIN (and maybe VLOOKUP? FILTER?) to make a list of IMPORTRANGES, resulting in something like `{IMPORTRANGE(C3,$E$1); IMPORTRANGE(C4,$E$1); IMPORTRANGE(C5,$E$1); IMPORTRANGE...}`?

Currently, in a google sheet, I have a formula that looks like this: `=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTRANGE(C3,$E$1);IMPORTRANGE(C4,$E$1);IMPORTRANGE(C5,$E$1);IMPORTRANGE..."` where spreadsheet urls are in Col C and a range (same for every imported sheet) is in E1.

Typing it all in was fine when I only had about a dozen spreadsheets I was importing and they all already existed. But now I want to import many more spreadsheets (I heard that the limit of 50 importranges no longer applies) and they don't all exist yet. If I keep things as they are, every time I add another spreadsheet url to Column C, I'll also have to go in and edit my =SORT formula.

Then I found this thread, [Fill ArrayFormula with dynamic ImportRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198117/fill-arrayformula-with-dynamic-importrange), which has a suggested answer listed as:   `="=sort(ARRAYFORMULA({"&JOIN(";",ArrayFormula("IMPORTRANGE("""&VLOOKUP(FILTER(G2:G20,G2:G20<>""),Sheet3!$A$2:$B,2,0)&""","""&G1&"!A2:B"")"))&"}),1,True,2,True)"`
The JOIN in there looks intriguing (I just recently learned about JOIN) but I don't understand all the syntax (like """) and I also can't access to original spreadsheet to see what the references point to.

So, I'm looking for help in how to input the C3, C4, C5, etc into the JOIN -- not sure how the VLOOKUP helps me -- and also if anyone knows why there are so many ="&=&"""s throughout the suggested formula...

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions below may do what you need. The first is what you requested. The second is the one which will probably work to combine multiple `IMPORTRANGE` formulas.

**SOLUTION 1**
`="="&ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(E3:E="","","IMPORTRANGE("&E3:E&", $E$1)"&":")),":"))),,9^99),"\)(.*?)I","\), I"))`

**SOLUTION 2**
`="=QUERY({"&ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(E3:E="","","IMPORTRANGE("&E3:E&", $E$1)"&":")),":"))),,9^99),"\)(.*?)I","\); I")&"},""Select Col1 where Col1<>''"",0)")`

You would then just copy the cell, select the destination cell and "paste as values" *into the formula bar*.

You can see the sheet in action [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vAPn6aAu74QWskZqMOqOxA2PcTs3-WM_WCUKxPbNR_M/edit?usp=sharing) (just make a copy of it to use).

Comment: Starting with solution 1, I realized I had to change the second to last , to a ; to get it to work. But then I could copy it and paste values, as you suggested, into the right spot of my sort formula. I wasn't sure what to do with Solution 2 until I realized I could change the "=QUERY... you gave to the "=sort(arrayformula... I needed. This is even better than Solution 1 since now I can paste in the full formula I need (using paste values in the formula bar) instead of just pasting in the importrange list into the sort formula.