# Using IMPORTRANGE as an array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, importrange

I have a URL in one cell which is the criterion for the IMPORTRANGE. e.g.:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(B2,"sheet1!$A$1")
```

I found a formula to collect it as criterion, but not in array version.

A sample can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yctlfcZHQtekYdn_jBXZBCj6WrHID-nBI0jJaUtVYAg/edit?usp=sharingthanks/shlomo).

Comment: Am I understanding correctly:  you are trying to use the provided IMPORTRANGE() formula in an ARRAYFORMULA() so you do not have to copy it down to each row?

Answer (score 2):

I see you have column B filled with Spreadsheet Ids, and you are trying to execute

```
=ArrayFormula(IMPORTRANGE(B2:B,"sheet1!$A$1"))
```

Not every spreadsheet function supports arrays as argument. In particular, `importrange` does not. You need separate `importrange` formulas for separate spreadsheets you are importing.

Indeed, importing data from another spreadsheet is not a batch operation; each import has to be authorized by clicking a prompt the first time it's called. Also, it's a very slow operation; you will get a serious performance
hit if trying to import a lot of other spreadsheets.

Generally, if you find yourself doing a lot of `importrange`, it may be time to rethink the overall data organization.

Comment: On top of what @zaq wrote, each file being imported will require you to allow access with the use of the importrange() function.  So when a new file link is added, any formula for that file will not work until you physically allow access. Custom script would get around this, but could be time consuming to run if the number of imported files grow.  [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-do-i-add-formulas-to-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script) has a script for copying formulas down

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot use `IMPORTRANGE()` in an arrayformula, as detailed in the other answer, you can use it in an array literal. In your case, for the first five cells in your column `B` that contain spreadsheet URLs:

```
={
  IMPORTRANGE(B2,"sheet1!$A$1");
  IMPORTRANGE(B3,"sheet1!$A$1");
  IMPORTRANGE(B4,"sheet1!$A$1");
  IMPORTRANGE(B5,"sheet1!$A$1");
  IMPORTRANGE(B6,"sheet1!$A$1")
}
```

So you'll have to write `IMPORTRANGE()` multiple times and you can only use this technique if you know before how many sheets there are to import. But the advantage is that this also works where `IMPORTRANGE()` returns multiple rows each – in that case, copying the formulas down is no option, as `IMPORTRANGE()` creates an error in cases where its results would overwrite cell contents further down.