# Loop column content from another tab and add extra text to output

Tags: google-sheets

## Objective

I have a column animal names in another tab (Animals) of the same google sheet.

| Animals |
| --- |
| ant |
| bat |
| cat |
| dog |

I am attempting to source that column of data into another sheet and append string text either side for it's output.

Eg: This is a [animal]. Isn't it cool.

| Animals Output |
| --- |
| This is called ant. Isn't it cool. |
| This is called bat. Isn't it cool. |
| This is called cat. Isn't it cool. |
| This is called dog. Isn't it cool. |

### Progress

I've been able to list the animals column into the destination tab using:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_url", "Animals!A1:A4")
```

#### Problem

I haven't been able to add the string text to the left and right of the output.

I've looked at:

1. Concatenate, but it breaks the reference for the import range:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_url", CONCATENATE(A2,"Animals!A1:A3"),A3)
```

2. Arrayformula, but that doesn't work with importrange as per:
   [Using IMPORTRANGE as an array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504050/using-importrange-as-an-array-formula)

**Can anyone point me in the right direct here please?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,importrange("URL","Sheet!A2:A"),
       map(Σ,lambda(z,if(z="",,"This is called "&z&". Isn't it cool."))))
```

[image]