# Vlookup in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hope that someone can help me with this,

I have a spreadsheet where I want to insert a specific vlookup on the cell where it returns the result I want if it searches A:A same as B:B it will return a result at C:C If true.

The current formula will be as below in the sheet

```
=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'A1,'Sheet2'!C:E,3,False)
```

Basically, Currently, I'm copying this formula to every row cell I have in the sheet which is kinda messy when someone wants to add in new row

How do I add in GAS where it will always return the formula in the cell with +1 in the formula? Meaning it will be as below in every row

```
=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'A1,'Sheet2'!C:E,3,False)
=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'A2,'Sheet2'!C:E,3,False)
=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'A3,'Sheet2'!C:E,3,False)
=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'A4,'Sheet2'!C:E,3,False)
=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'A5,'Sheet2'!C:E,3,False)
```

Comment: I am not good in codes, I had tried to use Set.Value ( " " ) but it unable to +1 everytime i created a new row. that's the closest i get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add formulas to Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-do-i-add-formulas-to-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'A1:A,'Sheet2'!C:E,3,0)))
```

Delete the VLOOKUP column. Copy and paste this formula in A1.

Comment: But it lead to another issue, As I am not able to add-in anything that I want to key in myself in Sheet1 C:C . I may need to key in manually myself if Sheet2 does not have what I key-in in Sheet1 A:A – Cheah Rae Von 1 hour ago