# Google Script Insert Formula to Non-Consecutive Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been searching for a solution for a while and have not been able to get one. I am new to Google apps script and appreciate any help with this newbie question.

Here is what I have:
`spreadsheet.getRangeList(['I5', 'I10', 'I15', 'I20']).setFormula('=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$EZ:$EZ,Sheet1!$BV:$BV,"Criteria",Sheet 1!$L:$L,$A5)');`

The problem is it will paste that formula to each of the cells without changing the  $A5 to $A10, $A15 and $A20, respectively.

Is it possible to do what I am asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using setFormula use setFormulaR1C1

Related

- [How do I add formulas to Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12036726/1595451)