# How to increment simple formula by 1 in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Disclaimer:** I'm a Google Apps Script newbie.

I'm trying to create a timesheet in Google Sheets that lets a user clock in & clock out to log hours on a given project. I've borrowed code from a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmGfkst7qRc) on the general structure of setting the whole thing up.

Here's what the blank time sheet looks like. It's pretty basic:

[image]

I've created a user button (off to the right) where the user presses "Start" and cell A2 will input a timestamp. Then the user can press an "End" button, and a second timestamp, this time in B2, will appear, along with a simple calculation in C2 that measures the delta in the two timestamps, thus giving a duration of time spent on a given task or project. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

When the user needs to press "Start" again, a new timestamp appears in cell A3, and so on so forth, along with a new delta calculation for each new row.

**Problem:** I'm unable to get the simple delta calculation in column C to increment down each new rows so that the `setFormula` function doesn't contain hardcoded references to cells A2 & B2. See below code for what I have so far:

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName) {
 return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue(); 
}

function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}


function addStartRecord (a) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a);
}

function addEndRecord (b, c) {
  var row = getNextRow()-1;
  setValue('B' + row, b);
  setValue('C' + row, c);
  }

function punchIn() {
 addSRecord(new Date()); 
}

function punchOut() {
  addERecord(new Date(), '=B2-A2');
}
```

The problem is with the `punchOut()` function there at the bottom. Any idea on the best way to increment this delta calculator down each new row?

**Note:** I saw a pretty good answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032272), but the code is throwing an error in the script editor after the line containing `data[i] = ['=A' + i+1.toString() + ' + 1 ' ]`. Also, I don't want to set a definitive last row for the delta calculation (such as 20 in this example). I'd want the user to be able to record as many new start/end times for a project as they'd want.

**Edit:** Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UNmNn7KbcxnuWCTaDruabDpwTOznyQUD7S9ZDzHLZO4/edit?usp=sharing) to the timesheet so you can test the code.

Comment: Could you provide your sheet (or a copy) with edit permissions to be able to test out the code? Also, is it possible for a user to press their start button before another user presses their end button? meaning, is this a single sheet for everyone?

Comment: Sure thing @AlbertoMolina - how do I do provide a sheet on this forum? Just post a link? And the sheet would just be for a single user.

Comment: You can update your question (edit) and include the link there, you get the share link from the spreadsheet itself, in the top-right you'll see the share button and there you can get the shareable link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modifying your punchOut method like this:

```
function punchOut() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = ss.getLastRow();
  addEndRecord(new Date(), '=B' + row + '-A' + row);
}
```

I tested it in the sheet and it worked well.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

`setFormula()` - this enables you to describe the formula to be inserted into column C.

The following is two simple functions that handle "Punch in" and "Punch Out" (with its calculation).

---

```
function so5695101401in() {
  // punchin
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lR = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row is "+lR);
  var punchinRange = sheet.getRange(lR+1, 1);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the punchinRange = "+punchinRange.getA1Notation());
  punchinRange.setValue(new Date());
}
function so5695101401out() {
  // punchout
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lR = sheet.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row is "+lR);
  var punchoutRange = sheet.getRange(lR, 2);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the punchoutRange = "+punchoutRange.getA1Notation());
  punchoutRange.setValue(new Date());
  var timeElapsed = sheet.getRange(lR, 3).setNumberFormat("hh:mm:ss");
  timeElapsed.setFormula("=B2-A2"); 
}
```

---

[setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Answer (score 0):

I use a workaround for this problem, via app script copy the cell with the formula to de new row or range!.
for you problem:

```
var formula1 = sheetDatos.getRange(lastRow, 3); //get the formula
var copyRange = sheetDatos.getRange(lastRow+1, 3);
formula1.copyTo(copyRange);
```

for me is more easy in this way, try to do in sheet to understand how this work.
you need a initial formula to go in this way ;)