# How to Insert Value into Another Cell Entirely

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We want to insert the formula =IF(E2="","","No") into column F of the attached Sheet if column E is **blank**. However, this is a bit tricky for a few reasons. Column F already has this formula. We have a separate apps script that basically overwrites this and inserts "Yes" when an email is sent. On "No" the email is sent, so "Yes" prevents the email sending again.

The apps script for trying to reset "Yes" back to the formula =IF(E2="","","No") is below. The issue is that if you have "Yes" in column F, even when column E has values (not "" as the code says), it somehow converts the "Yes" into "No". The issue seems to be that the code overwrites **all** of column F with the function, rather than the cells that just have column E blank. We are not experts at this so your patience and guidance is appreciated!

```
function updateEformula(){
  
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Active Student List") 

  var values = ss.getRange("E2:E").getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
        if (values[i] == ""){
         
          var rangeEToModify = ss.getRange("E2:E");
          rangeEToModify.setValue('=IFERROR(INDEX(StudentMatches!B:B,Match(A2,StudentMatches!D:D,0)),"")'); 
          var rangeFToModify = ss.getRange("F2:F");
          rangeFToModify.setValue('=IF(E2="","","No")'); 
        }
      }}
```

Comment: Why not have app script do everything?  Forget the formula.

Comment: We had the idea but didn't know where to start :) We will work on something and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Ok, so we have no updated the code. However, for some reason if I type "Yes" into column F, even when column E has values (not "" as the code says), it somehow converts the "Yes" into "No". We have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Using ranges specified like this `ss.getRange("E2:E").getValues();` often results in nulls between lastrow and maxrows

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, the example solution causes our code to keep running and the the execution doesn't stop. Maybe there's something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459499/18283992) provided most of the answer above. However, we adjusted the last 2 lines so that the formulas adjust for each row in the sheet. This required the use of template literals. I borrowed the example of usage of template literals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032272/18283992).

```
function updateEFformulas() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Active Student List");
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 5, sh.getLastRow() - 1);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == "") {
      sh.getRange(i+2,5).setValue('=IFERROR(INDEX(StudentMatches!B:B,Match' + '(A' + (i+2) + ',StudentMatches!D:D,0)),"")');
      sh.getRange(i+2,6).setValue('=IF' + '(E' + (i+2) + '="","","No")')
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Insert formula into a column of cells

```
function updateEformula() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Active Student List");
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 5, sh.getLastRow() - 1);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == "") {
      sh.getRange(i+2,5).setFormula(formula for row i + 2,column 5);
      sh.getRange(i+2,6).setFormula(formule for row i+2,column 6)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Cooper! However, how do we make it so that each formula is custom per row? If we insert ('=IFERROR(INDEX(StudentMatches!B:B,Match(A2,StudentMatches!D:D,0)),"")') for row i+2, column 5 it inserts that for each row rather than A3, A4, A5, etc. for corresponding rows? Same thing for the other formula.

Comment: I would use template literals

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! We looked up what those are and are unsure how to apply them here. For instance, would it be sh.getRange(i+2,5).setFormula ( `=IFERROR(INDEX(StudentMatches!B:B,Match({A},StudentMatches!D:D,0)),"")` ) ? However, this doesn't seem to work. I did put the ` ` between =IFERROR and the last parentheses, but this comment adds it as code.

Comment: I have not used formulas for 15 years so I can't help you.  Just do it by trial and error, you will get it sooner or later.

Comment: However, if someone else has an idea please help! Thanks.

Comment: Got it! Please see the answer below. Thanks again @Cooper for all your help on all our posts.