# How to append a formula to inbound data capture in Apps Scripts for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Upon importing data on a new row append, I want one of the columns to add formula that references the column number that is being created.

Hi!
I am trying to push data to a google sheet, to do this we have found a script that we can automatically push our data too and it will post it to the relevant sheet (the code is as follows):

```
function doPost(e) {
  // Open the requested SpreadSheet and Sheet:
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(prop.getProperty('spreadsheetUrl'));
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  
  // Append the data to the sheet on a new row:
  sheet.appendRow([new Date(), e.parameter['from'], e.parameter['message']]);
  
  // Return a empty text string
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("");
}
```

As per instructions from [here](https://medium.com/46-thoughts/receive-sms-into-google-spreadsheet-435b51393493)

Now, we have another source of data in another tab on the same sheet, where we want to flag records that appear in sheet one, but are already in sheet two and vice versa.

To do this, I can use the function:
`=iferror(match(B2,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$999,0),0)`

Now, if I try to pre-populate the sheet with this on all fields, it won't work as new data is appended to the bottom (because we use the `new` function)

So, I assume I need to add it to this line of code:

```
  sheet.appendRow([new Date(), e.parameter['from'], e.parameter['message']]);
```

However, I cannot add it as a straight function, so based off info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-do-i-add-formulas-to-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script)
I tried:
`cell.setFormula`

However, I need cell to be a variable based off the new row that is being created.
So I am a bit lost!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would have  expected the data to be in e.postData.contents and I might have expected it to be in JSON so I might have guessed that it needs to be parsed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can append formulas but I think you can do with setValues() so try:

`sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,4).setValues([[new Date(),value1,value2,formula]]);`

Comment: Hi @Cooper, 
Thanks for the help! 

I have tried changing the code to be: 
`sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,4).setValues([[new Date(), e.parameter['from'], e.parameter['message'], "INSERT Formula"]]);`

However, no matter what I put in that last column, it doesn't push to the sheet.
Ideally I want the above formula, `=iferror(match(B2,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$999,0),0)` 

Do I need to format this as  `.setFormula(=iferror(match(B2,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$999,0),0))`
The next issue is that in that formula the cell B2 needs to be col B row whatever has just been created

Comment: Please show me the entire function and I'll help you figure it out