# Google Apps Script - Assistance Adding a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, syntax-error

[Formula works on RMA sheet, Cell A2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPvTM.png)

[After Formula on RMA Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDYNl.png)

I have a Google sheets workbook filled with different sheets (1 main sheet "HelpDesk Tickets").
In the main sheet "HelpDesk Tickets" Column E there is different data based off of ticket categories (8 total) which have sheets named after the categories.

I use a formula which works when ran from the cell A2 in each of the different sheets based off of the ticket categories column "E" from the main sheet (HelpDesk Tickets). I change the sheet name as needed in the formula.

Ex..
From the sheet named "RMA", cell A2, I enter the Formula which copies All rows from  the main sheet "HelpDesk Tickets" based off of Column E with "RMA" as a value in any of the cells into the "RMA" sheet. These sheets are used to keep tickets organized for graphs etc. My issue is I cannot get the formula to work when adding it to Apps Script.

Formula (this works)
=query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)

I have tried looking at other forums and sites as I feel this should be really simple to add but cannot figure it out for the life of me.
Sites
[Google Support 184049281](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/184049281/i-need-help-adding-formulas-with-google-apps-script?hl=en)
[Stack Overflow 12036726](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-do-i-add-formulas-to-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script)

I took the example from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) and tried to change it with what I need and still did not work

---

↓ **Current Script** ↓

---

function sheetRMA(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");
cell.setFormula("**=query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)**");

}

---

↓ **Error**  ↓

---

Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 7 file: TC_RMA.gs

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. For example, if you want to remove your error of `I keep getting error Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 7 file: TC_RMA.gs`, please modify `sheet.getRange("B5"); cell.setFormula("=query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)");` to ``sheet.getRange("B5"); cell.setFormula(`=query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)`);``. But, I cannot understand your actual question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: @Tanaike , My question is how do I add my working formula to apps script? 

=query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)

The formula is ran from sheet "RMA" cell A2, which checks a different sheet "Helpdesk Tickets" Column E if there is any value named RMA and copies the rows from Helpdesk Tickets to RMA sheet

I tried the code in the main question starting with               function sheetRMA(){

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `My question is how do I add my working formula to apps script?`, if my understanding is correct, in this case, the modification in my comment might be an answer. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike , that did not work, I edited my question to add pictures at the very top. I need a to add the formula to Apps script

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `that did not work`, can you add your current script in your question? Unfortunately, I cannot understand your detailed situation from `that did not work`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: By the way, although I have already asked in my 1st comment, is your question to remove the error of `I keep getting error Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 7 file: TC_RMA.gs`? Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `that did not work`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike , Thank you for your help. I updated the question to show the script. I only wish to  add the Formula to apps script.  =query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your current script, I noticed that you don't use my proposed modification. I apologize for this. So, I posted the modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike , I tested your suggestion and it now runs with NO error but it does nothing. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your error of `Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 7 file: TC_RMA.gs` was resolved. About `but it does nothing`, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike when I run the formula in cell A2 it works and copies the rows from a different sheet. When I run your script it says "Execution Completed" but does nothing. I assigned your script to a button and it runs but nothing gets copied from a different sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `but does nothing`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your actual expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike this is what is needed and expected. Sheet2 searches sheet1 column E for any row with the word "RMA". If it finds the word "RMA" it copies the row to sheet2

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added a sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike , the sample script provided works. WooHoo   ....Thank you!!!!! You are awesome #(1️⃣).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `↓ Current Script ↓` of your updated question, unfortunately, I noticed that you don't use my proposed modification. And, I'm worried that my comment might be low readability when the script is put in the comment. So, I would like to add it as an answer. Please modify your script as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
function sheetRMA(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("A2"); cell.setFormula("=query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)");

}
```

#### To:

```
function sheetRMA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");
  cell.setFormula(`=query('HelpDesk Tickets'!A:F, "where E = 'RMA' ",0)`);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> this is what is needed and expected. Sheet2 searches sheet1 column E for any row with the word "RMA". If it finds the word "RMA" it copies the row to sheet2

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const values = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[4].includes("RMA"));
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```