# Updating the formula with dynamic reference in a spreadsheet range in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have many similar google spreadsheet to modify , so i'm working on a function to do it through app script
I need to modify dynamic formula of each cell of a range.

Example :
formula of the cell H7 : Mod(F7-C7+G7+$E$4;1)
the formula is the same for all the cell of the range H7:H39 (ex for H10 -> formula : = Mod(F10-C10+G10+$E$4;1)

What i want is if i specify the range (ex: H7:H39) and the new formula my function will update all the formulas depending of the row number .

So is there a simple way to do it in app script ? or do i need to create my function from scratch ?

Comment: Isn't MOD(number,1) always 0?

Comment: i use mod because my data are duration

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple custom formula to calculate the values.  Since you want to use the values from C to G I get the range as a 2D Array and then loop through the array

[image]

```
function MyMOD(range,mod) {
  // if range is string get the values, otherwise its an Array
  if( typeof range === "string" ) {
    range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getValues();
  }
  let e4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E4").getValue();
  range = range.map( row => [(row[3]-row[0]+row[4]+e4) % mod] );
  return range;
}
```

Comment: I finally find what i was looking for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036726/how-do-i-add-formulas-to-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script